# How can I prove that the results in the following sequence will always share the same factor?

Tags: proof-explanation, factoring, prime-factorization

The following sequence is built of $((A^z)^x -1)/6$ where $z$ increases by $1$ and the conditions for $A$ must be that $(A - 1) \mod 6 = 0$ and for $x$ must be that $x$ is odd and $x > 1$:

$((A^1)^x -1)/6 $ , $((A^2)^x-1)/6$ , $((A^3)^x-1)/6$ , $((A^4)^x-1)/6$ ...

How can i prove that the results in the sequence will always have the same factor?

Examples:

$(7^3-1)/6 =57$ , $(49^3-1)/6 =19608$ , $(343^3-1)/6 = 6725601$....

$57, 19608, 6725601$ all have a factor of $19$

$(7^5-1)/6 =2801$ , $(49^5-1)/6 = 47079208$ , $(343^5-1)/6 = 791260261657$....

$2801, 47079208, 791260261657$ all have a factor of $2801$

$(13^3-1)/6 =366$ , $(169^3-1)/6 =1 804468$ , $(2197^3-1)/6 = 1767416562$....

$366, 804468, 1767416562$ all have a factor of $61$

Comment: $A^x-1$ divides $A^{nx}-1$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner That is a one way to simplify it, but I still don’t understand the proof for why it must divide

Comment: $(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)=a^n-1$

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Sometimes i get caught in what seems so complicated until I get a simple answer that makes me wonder how could i have missed it. I don't know if this question has value in staying open, but for me I got my answer with J.W. Tanner's comments

Comment: I believe it is called a “brain fart” moment

Comment: Update: I have used the info here to ask a more relevant  question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4014750/does-the-following-relate-to-the-beals-conjecture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Use $a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)$ with $a=A^x$.