# Why Is there no consistent factor in $A^2$ versus the other $A^X$ In the following sequence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

The following sequence is built of $((A^z)^x -1)/6$ where $z$ increases by $1$ and the conditions for $A$ must be that $(A - 1) \mod 6 = 0$ and for $x$ must be that $x$ is odd and $x > 1$:

$((A^1)^x -1)/6 $ , $((A^2)^x-1)/6$ , $((A^3)^x-1)/6$ , $((A^4)^x-1)/6$ ...

Examples:

$(7^3-1)/6 =57$ , $(49^3-1)/6 =19608$ , $(343^3-1)/6 = 6725601$....

$57, 19608, 6725601$ all have a factor of $19$

$(7^5-1)/6 =2801$ , $(49^5-1)/6 = 47079208$ , $(343^5-1)/6 = 791260261657$....

$2801, 47079208, 791260261657$ all have a factor of $2801$

$(13^3-1)/6 =366$ , $(169^3-1)/6 =1 804468$ , $(2197^3-1)/6 = 1767416562$....

$366, 804468, 1767416562$ all have a factor of $61$

**Where as if $x$ is allowed to be $x=2$:**

$(7^2-1)/6 = 8$ , $(49^2-1)/6 = 400$ , $(343^2-1)/6 = 19608$ , $(2401^2-1)/6 = 960800$....

$8$ has a factor of $2$

$400$ has factors of $2,5$

$19608$ has factors of $2,3,19,49$

$960800$ has factors  $2,3,5,1201$

As you can see there is no consistency in a common factor besides $2$.

$(11^2-1)/6 = 20$ , $(121^2-1)/6 = 2440$ , $(1331^2-1)/6 = 295260$....

$20$ has factors of $2,5$

$2440$ has factors of $2,5,61$

$295260$ has factors of $2,3,5,7, 19, 37$

As you can see there is no consistency in a common factor besides $2$ and $5$ ($5$ for obvious reasons related to the multiplications of 11).

The reason I allow myself to compare $x=2$ with other odd values where $x > 1$ is because $2$ is the only even prime.

From there on if $x$ is a multiplication of $2$ it can be rewritten in a way that $x$ is prime factor. Example $3^6=729$ can be written as $9^3$

The comparison is then reduced to a comparison between prime numbers with different $x$, and the result is that when $x=2$, there is no consistent common factor unlike when $x ≠ 2$

Why is there no consistent common factor when $x=2$?

Notes:

*I don’t take into account the common factors of 2,3 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence that you are studying is the sequence of numbers $$\frac{A^{2z}-1}{6}, z=1,2,3,...$$
Since $$A^{2z}-1=(A^2-1)(1+A^2+A^4+ ... +A^{2z-2})$$ there is a consistent common factor of $$\frac{A^{2}-1}{6}.$$

In your example with $A=7$ this common factor is $8$.

The next $A$ would be $13$ and then the common factor would be $28$ which contains the prime $7$ and so is not in your excluded set of $\{2,3,5\}$.